# j2ME-detect mobile number

Tags: java, java-me, emulation, java-wireless-toolkit

How do you detect the emulator mobile number in the Sun's Wireless toolkit?

Comment: (Is your caps-lock key stuck or something?)

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK it is not possible with currently available J2ME API's.. And my doubt is, Does emulator having mobile number?

Comment: yes @bhakki emulators having mobile no. When you run emulator its header shows something like "+5550000" that is emulators mobile no.

Comment: Hmmm. Ok mihir. I didn't check with before. But we dont have that API in j2me.

Answer (score 0):

Nope no way to do this programatically.  Why not prompt the user?  If they are happy with you having their mobile number, they will enter it for you.